# What sort of transformation is a 3d cubic tensor?

Tags: linear-algebra, tensors, multilinear-algebra

I was curious about tensors and higher dimensional matrices. I know what a tensor is. But I can find next to no readable information about what or how to actually work with them? In short, what kind of transformation is a say 2x2x2 cubic tensor? What are it's inputs and outputs? And there an analogue of matrix multiplication for 3d tensors that is analogous to composition of linear maps like it is for matrices? In general, can you extend other concepts from linear algebra into these 3d matrices? I know tensor problems in general are NP hard, but what about in the case of either cubic tensors or tensors of a fixed order? And even if they are NP hard, is it known what the generic complexity looks like? And are the problems efficiently computable in practice? I am a high school senior, but I am interested in higher math, so please don't make this too complex. I taught myself basic linear algebra on my own. I am fine with a long answer however, as long as everything is clearly defined.

Comment: For starters, a $2\times 2$ matrix can represent three types of tensors, only one of which is linear transformations. There is no product in the other two cases.

Comment: @Colonizor You have quite a few questions in there, it might be best to narrow things down to something that can be addressed with a relatively short answer

Comment: @Colonizor To give a few quick answers: in order to be placed into a universal framework, tensors are typically thought of as multilinear maps that take a certain number of vectors and "covectors" as inputs and produce a scalar as their output. For instance, a linear map from $V$ to $W$ would be thought of as multilinear map that takes in one vector from $V$ and one covector from $W^*$ to produce a scalar output. With this in mind, there are 3 possible interpreations of a 2-dimensional tensor and 4 possible interpretations of a 3-dimensional tensor

Comment: @Colonizor The natural generalization of the product of matrices in the context of tensors is a [contraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_contraction) of the product $T \otimes U$

Comment: @Ben Grossmann What confuses me is that the output of a linear map here would be a scalar. Shouldn't a matrix transform a vector into another vector?

Comment: @Colonizor48 Once you narrow things down in your question, I can clarify things in a complete answer when I get the chance. The quick explanation is this: in this context, we think of the (vector) output of the linear transformation as itself being a function that takes a covector and produces a vector. That is, for a linear map $L:V \to W$ and $v \in V$, we can think of $L(v)$ as being the map from $W^*$ to the scalars given by $[L(v)](f) = f(L(v))$...

Comment: ... The tensor $T$ corresponding to $L$ is the [uncurried](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) version of this function: $T: V \times W^* \to \Bbb F$ is given by $T(v,f) = f(L(v))$

Comment: @Colonizor You might find [this table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor#Examples) of examples to be informative. One example of a 3 dimensional tensor is the cross-product. We normally think of it as a bilinear map that has two vector inputs and one vector output, but with the above formalism we can instead think of it as a multilinear map that takes in 2 vectors and 1 covector, and outputs a scalar. In general, multilinear maps that take a pair of vectors to a vector output are a kind of 3-dimensional tensor.

Comment: @Ben Grossmann My question should be a bit more concise now.